# How to use QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS with SUBDIRS?

Tags: qt, qmake

I want to provide a make target that should be optional and not executed in normal build process, only if you explicitly specify it. Usually you specify that like this:

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += fooTarget
```

It is executed later like this:

```
make fooTarget
```

However my project is a subdirs project. The target only gets executed for the top level project, but not for sub projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mark the target as recursive in the top level project file:

```
fooTarget.CONFIG = recursive
```

Now it will be executed for every sub project (but not their sub projects) when you run `make fooTarget`. If the target does not exist in one sub project, `make` will fail. The behavior can be changed to only execute the target on certain directories or to call a different target for sub projects. See [Adding Custom Targets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets) in the qmake documentation.